# Error while Sorting on table from Server side: "At least one object must implement IComparable."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I have a datatable that has total 23 Columns in the `IEnumerable<AdjustmentErrorCodes> adjustmentErrorFile;`

This **AdjustmentErrorCodes** is defined as:

```
public class AdjustmentErrorCodes
{
    public AdjustmentErrorCodes();

    public string AdjustmentErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string AdjustmentErrorCodesDescription { get; set; }
    public **List<AdjustmentErrorDetails>** AdjustmentErrorDetails { get; set; }
    public int AdjustmentErrorTypesKey { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to sort on any column from Serverside. If it is for SortColumn Index 0 or 1, it is working fine.
I am trying to sort from any other columns that are from  List, then the error is throwing at return **a.AdjustmentErrorDetails.Select(b => b.CaseDisplayId);** as
Error:   "At least one object must implement IComparable."
Source: mscorlib

Anyone have any idea how to sort from list within the List. Appreciate your suggestions.
Thank you for your time.

```
Func<AdjustmentErrorCodes, object> orderingFunction = (a =>
                   {
                       if (sortColumnIndex == 0)
                       {
                           return a.AdjustmentErrorCode;
                       }

  else if (sortColumnIndex == 1)
                            return a.AdjustmentErrorCodesDescription;

                       else
return **a.AdjustmentErrorDetails.Select(b => b.CaseDisplayId);**

                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

For column 0 or 1, you're sorting by a *single value*. That's fine. Otherwise you're sorting by a *sequence*. What does that even mean? If one `AdjustmentErrorCode` has a sequence of `CaseDisplayIds` of `{ 1, 5, 3 }` and another has a sequence of `{ 2, 4 }`, which should come first?

Note that your sorting is definitely happening in your .NET code, *not* in the database. Is that really what you want?

Additionally, I would suggest that rather than check `sortColumnIndex` on each iteration, you use different lambda expressions:

```
Func<AdjustmentErrorCodes, object> orderingFunction;
switch (sortColumnIndex)
{
    case 0: orderingFunction = a => a.AdjustmentErrorCode; break;
    case 1: orderingFunction = a => a.AdjustmentErrorCodeDescription; break;
    default: orderingFunction = ...;
}
```

(Or write a method for that switch statement which *returns* the value, and call it with:

```
var orderingFunction = CreateOrdering(sortColumnIndex);
```

That way the assignments can be turned into return statements, and you can lose the `break;` statements :)